# Turn off subwoofer through Windows

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, speakers

I have [Logitech Z313](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/speaker-system-z313) speakers which include a subwoofer. My question is is it possible to turn off the subwoofer (or heavily mute it) using settings in Windows 8.1? I am using VIA HD Audio, but there are very few settings in this program for adjusting anything.

When I play music at night the subwoofer sometimes is too loud and that is why I ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot directly control your subwoofer from your computer.

Your speakers are only 2 channel - they use the standard stereo 1/8" TRS connector to the PC.  Thus, there is no dedicated subwoofer output that you could possibly control from the PC, only the standard two-channel stereo mix.

[image]

An option you might have is to use your media player or sound card driver's graphic equalizer feature to cut down some of the very low frequencies.

Comment: Its pretty unusual - most speakers of that ilk have a seperate volume control for the subwoofer, but this dosen't seem to.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I did find another setting in Windows called Low Frequency Protection which does a lot of the same as the equalizer. It cuts out all lows.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  I use Realtek, though, and there is a mixer setting (see if yours has an equivalent).  I found that turning these 2 settings down in the equalizer turned my subwoofer off.  If VIA has this, then try turning those dials down.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I also have a Realtek audio card, but the Realtek equalizer seems to be disabled and instead I found an installed application called Dolby Audio. I'm still playing with the (unlabeled..) equalizer.

[image]